# How to find value from comma-separated column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am wondering how to write a SQL statement for SQL Server 2008 that selects entries where a column contains a comma-delimited value (usually - there could only be one entry (and no leading comma)) for instance:

```
Column1
---------------------------
10-15,20-30,31-97,104-187
```

Values in the column represents comma delimited ranges.
In this case I want to find `25`.

Comment: There is no 25 in above example

Comment: Actually  value 20-30 means (Exist all value between 20 and 30).. sorry i couldn't ask proper Question. Is it possible to find.                                  For example :
I have two table Table1(Column1,Cloumn2) and Table2 These data 10-15,20-30,31-97,104-187
are coming from Table1 and sitting in Table2 as a comma seperated.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider normalizing your database. You are adding insult to injury by using a single column to keep multiple ranges data. A normalized database would have another table for the ranges, with a start value and an end value, along with a foreign key to the original table.
Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tblRange
(
    Range_itemId int, --(fk to the original table)
    Range_From int,
    Range_To int
)
```

Should you do this, your query would be simply:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM tblItems
INNER JOIN tblRange ON(Item_Id = Range_ItemId)
WHERE Range_From <= 25
AND Range_To >= 25
```

However, if you can't normalize your database then you would have to use a [split string](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) function to create rows from your comma delimited column, and then parse the text of each row to find what is the range of each row.
Here is an example:

create demo table

```
CREATE TABLE ZZZItems
(
    ItemId int identity(1,1),
    ItemRanges varchar(500)
)
```

populate demo table

```
INSERT INTO ZZZItems VALUES
('10 - 20, 20 - 30, 30 - 40'),
('40 - 50, 50 - 60, 60 - 70'),
('70 - 80, 80 - 90, 90 - 100'),
('10 - 20, 20 - 30, 30 - 40')
```

using [`CROSS APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) to a split function table and extracting the ranges from the splitted data

```
    ;WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT  ItemId, 
                CAST(LEFT(Data, CHARINDEX('-', Data) - 1) As Int) As RangeFrom, 
                CAST(RIGHT(Data, LEN(Data) - CHARINDEX('-', Data)) As Int) As RangeTo
        FROM ZZZItems 
        CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(ItemRanges, ',')
    )

    -- select the item ids where the requested number fits in the range.
    SELECT ItemId
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE RangeFrom < 25 
    AND RangeTo > 25
```

clean up

```
DROP TABLE ZZZItems
```

Results:

```
ItemId
-----------
1
4
```

I didn't add the split function, you should choose your own from the article I've linked to.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)